# How do I make a container height fit dynamic content sizes

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement [this card flip feature](https://codepen.io/thepaperescape/pen/yLzYObb), but need the height of the container to fit all of the content. Note that the back of the card has more content that the front.

Ultimately, the content of each card will be dynamic and will therefor need varying height to adequately contain the content. How do I achieve this? I've tried making the height of the container set to 100% and auto to no avail. Thoughts?

Here's the code in full:

````
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p>6</p>
      <p>7</p>
      <p>8</p>
      <p>9</p>
      <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p>6</p>
      <p>7</p>
      <p>8</p>
      <p>9</p>
      <p>10</p>
      <p>11</p>
      <p>12</p>
      <p>13</p>
      <p>14</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try `min-height: 100%;` instead of `height: 100%;` in `.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back`.  And you'll have to move the `box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);`  to `.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back` otherwise it will apply to the initial height and you'll get a shadow in the middle of the back side of your card.
See working snippet.

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p>6</p>
      <p>7</p>
      <p>8</p>
      <p>9</p>
      <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p>6</p>
      <p>7</p>
      <p>8</p>
      <p>9</p>
      <p>10</p>
      <p>11</p>
      <p>12</p>
      <p>13</p>
      <p>14</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's definitely a step in the right direction! Do you know how we could make it so both sides of the card match the max height needed? For example: the back of the card is taller than the front due to containing more information than the front. Is there a way to make the front match the height needed for the back? I've created a new codepen [here](https://codepen.io/thepaperescape/pen/xxXwONZ) with your code for reference.

Comment: I don't think you can handle that with css alone.  Would likely have to get the element height with javascript and apply the height inline to your flip cards.  Check out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetheight.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `height: max-content` in modern browsers.

When applied to the container, the contents inside will dictate its height.

Comment: `height: max-content;` would work if you were only concerned about the front side of card, it won't work on the back side card when flipped when the height is greater.  Plus it's really only has partial browser support... except in later versions of chrome.